# how to set time out in greenplum?

Tags: jdbc, timeout, greenplum

when i execute greenplum sql :

alter table  dw_crm_reports.dwd_agg_prodsalesinfo  set with (reorganize=true);

After 1800 seconds, the following error is returned:

[Pivotal][Greenplum JDBC Driver]Execution timeout expired.

how to set execution timeout in greenplum ,I can't find a way to set

Answer (score 0):

What client tool are you using?

It is possible the client tool you are using to execute your sql statement is setting a timeout, such as `statement_timeout` , prior to running the query.

You can look at the pg_log and see if any `SET` statements are run prior to your query.

Comment: Using the java client   , I tried using set statement_timeout = xxxxxxxxx, but it still doesn't work